# Entropy in a chess game

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

For entropy to be correct, i mean, that increases over time, in a chess game, there should be more options as game time goes on. But it's the opposite. Why?

Comment: Are you considering the information entropy about the configuration of the pieces on the board? are you considering the removal of pieces? If you remove a piece, this should make entropy decrease. It's kind of a open system, with pieces mainly flowing outwards the domain. It's just a comment, maybe a hint. For more rigorous answer, tomorrow. I'll follow the discussion. Very interesting question, to me

Comment: @Dale I for one think that this is a *very* interesting question, and the two serious answers below show that I am not alone in this view but it was downvoted. I sure would like to know why.

Comment: A chess game is not a thermodynamic system, but it *is* a system with a bounded phase space, so it's not surprising, if it is indeed correct that number of moves is analogous to energy input and number of possible future games is analogous to entropy (a claim on whose veracity I do not feel qualified to speculate) we find some peak entropy (in our case, the arbitrarily selected legal starting configuration) beyond which the analogous quantity to boltzmann temperature is negative.

Comment: "For entropy to be correct..." What do you mean by that?

Comment: that it increases over time, in a chess game.

Comment: It's a mistake to use the term "entropy" for rearrangements of macroscopic entities. All the arrangements have zero entropy because for each of them there is just one arrangement consistent with the macroscopic parameters.

Comment: @basics I believe you have stated the correct answer. A chess game is not a closed system since pieces can leave the board so there is no requirement for entropy to increase. In fact, it's just the opposite. The goal is to reduce the number of states until only one (checkmate) remains.

Comment: @MayaRahto "that it increases over time, in a chess game." There is no requirement for "entropy" to increase over time "in a chess game." First of all, you have no clear definition of what you even mean by "entropy" of a chess game (do you mean the positions on the board or what?). Second, a chess game is not an **isolated** system, and there is no reason to even believe in the first place that its "entropy" "should" increase. For example, when you freeze a tray of water in your freezer to make ice cubes the entropy of the tray/water system decreases (it is not an isolated system).

Comment: @MayaRahto Do you mean the Information/Gibb Entropy? If so, how are you defining the probabilities in the equation for entropy?

Comment: @hft, thank you for the reply. I'm the one who least know physics, but i mean information  entropy, yes. As Andrew argued, it is similar to the branching factor, but not equal, it is a little harder to define. I just ask looking for an answer, not that i know the answer.

Comment: The question is about *information entropy*, it is really more appropriate for statistics or computer science community.

Answer (score 7):

The *thermodynamic entropy* certainly increases during a chess game. For example, if you have two human opponents, they are each breathing, pumping blood, digesting, metabolizing -- all of these processes create heat. If one or more of the opponents is a computer, irreversible processes generate heat in the computer and will also increase the thermodynamic entropy. So the second law of thermodynamics is not contradicted by the existence of chess.

If you are referring to entropy in the sense of counting the number of possible chess position configurations -- essentially, an information theoretic entropy instead of a thermodynamic entropy -- then the second law of thermodynamics does not make any statements saying the entropy of a chess position should increase, so there's no reason (a priori) to expect the entropy to increase or decrease.

However, the number of possible board positions does increase in chess as you increase the move number, so in that sense the entropy defined in that way *does* increase. Another way to say that is that your odds of guessing the correct position go down with time. For each previous board position, there is typically more than one legal move, so the number of available positions is increasing. Eventually perhaps you reach a steady state where all positions have resulted in a draw or win, you might consider that a kind of "equilibrium state."

Comment: each move increases the chances of a winner and decreases the game's moves. it narrows to a winner.

Comment: @MayaRahto The entropy measures the total number of possible states. This is increasing; from the start, with each move, the number of *possible* positions of the board increases exponentially. What you are talking about is different; how much the number of states increases with each move. You are right, that in the middle game, there are more possibilities per move, then are there are in the end game. But this is not saying the entropy is decreasing, it is saying that the rate of increase of entropy is decreasing. (Also interesting but subtly different).

Comment: If the two competitors are equally capable and know the next step of the adversary, the entropy is zero, the game even start, i think. other than that, we have to assume equal capabilities for each player and one must take the first decision, after that we could calculate if there is indeed more possibilities in middle game, or if, how many turns it takes. As soon each decision is made, a lot of possibilities are lost. It does have more in the beggining, but they diminish considerably in time. I wish i know how to calculate this.

Comment: Also, taking this last argument, that they are equal and capable, and know eachother next step, the game is decided in the beggining. I mean, no free will for the players. Is the entropy still zero as the game was already decided?

Comment: @MayaRahto You might find this analysis interesting: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23135/what-is-the-average-number-of-legal-moves-per-turn/24325#24325. Note that the keyword for what you are asking about is the *branching factor*, not the *entropy*.

Comment: thank you. I noticed, it is not the same thing, but may i ask, are they a little related?

Comment: @MayaRahto They are but it's complicated. Consider a simpler game than chess, where at every turn you can make one of $B$ moves, and suppose $B$ is a fixed number (like 2) ($B$ is the branching factor). Then after $N$ turns, the total number of possible configurations $\Omega$ is given by $\Omega=B^N$. Assuming each possible configuration is equally likely, the entropy is then $S=\ln \Omega = N \ln B$. In chess there is also a relationship, but it is more complicated to compute $\Omega$ in terms of $B$ and $N$, since $B$ changes depending on the position on the board (as you pointed out).

Comment: @Andrew Does a past state returns to exist in a chess game?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a fitting interpretation of classical entropy.

Rather, from the very beginning you now everything about every field on the chess board. If I ask you about a randon field, say, C6, then you can with a blindfold on tell me exactly which chess piece, if any, that is located there.

But as game time progresses, you know less and less about each individual field and your guess will more and more often be wrong.

Comment: In the beggining of the game, at turn 0, we had all probabilities. But as soon the pieces are moved, the probability narrows.
Per example, turning back a movement, in most times give an advantage turn to the competitor. It does look like increasing probability, but i think actually does not.  And we dont play chess like this, its played to win, not to move the pieces like a barbie role play. So, if you take that in consideration, the game narrow to a winner. 
I dont know if i express correctly, sorry.

Comment: @MayaRahto You are probably assuming that the game is finite because the players agree on a draw if neither can win. Otherwise even though the number of positions is finite the game could go on forever. I am not sure how one would define (information) entropy in that case.

Comment: @MayaRahto I do not agree that "we have all the probability" by the beginning of the game, and I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by this. The probability of you guessing correctly - meaning your amount of certainty - when asked to a random macrostate, seems to *decrease* with game time. This corresponds to what is sometimes called increased chaos, which corresponds to increasing entropy. (By the way, the fact that chess pieces can leave the board means that you must include the table on which you place lost pieces in your system.)